!pip install or pip install inside jupyter notebook
It is possible to pip install a Python package inside a code cell in a Jupyter Notebook (I am running Jupyter lab). In the past the command was !pip install (as it was a system command), but for a while now it seems that just pip install also works. I haven't been able to sort out if pip install always works in a code cell or that sometimes !pip install is required. Does anybody know?

The magic version was added in 2019 and should be what is used these days. It was added to ensure the installation occurs in environment  where the kernel is running, which the command in conjunction with the exclamation point never did and could cause issues. See more about the modern %pip install command here. It is best to be explicit and use the % symbol so that your students adopt current best practices that now work universally in Jupyter since JupyterLite & even ...

 Google Colab now support it. For further context, The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

Pip is a magic command in jupyter notebook, as such it can be called with
%pip

which should replace calls of !pip in all places.
What you are observing, is probably the automagic feature that allows you to just write pip in you cell without % (or !) and it will automatically call pip for your current python interpreter (that is of course given that there is no variable named pip currently set, as that would take preference before the magic command)
Note that automagic is on by default in IPython kernels, see the docs:

InteractiveShell.automagic
Enable magic commands to be called without the leading %.
Trait type:       Bool
Default:        True
CLI option:     --automagic


Ah. That clarifies things a bit. Am I correct to assume the automagic feature is turned on in (many) standard installations (e.g., anaconda)? All students in my class seem to have automagic on by default without turning it on.

Yes, it should be on by default, I have added that to my answer
